# Split values in a column and create a matrix of column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to have a solution for my problem with minimum effort.

Question:

I have a list of values with delimited values. I would like to split and arrange each values at the appropriate cell. Column Heading should be also populated.

## Input

```
A,B,C
C,D,A,E
D,E
```

## Output

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| VLUE1 | VLUE2 | VLUE3 | VLUE4 | VLUE5 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| A     | B     | C     |       |       |
| A     |       | C     | D     | E     |
|       |       |       | D     | E     |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I have a solution using sorting, key value pair in python and iterating but i would like to know is there any shortcut using Python packages or panda?

-Sam

Comment: Is your input exactly `"A, B, C\nC, D, A, E\nD, E"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with a series -

```
s

0      A,B,C
1    C,D,A,E
2        D,E
dtype: object
```

Convert `s` to a OHE matrix using `get_dummies` -

```
x = s.str.get_dummies(sep=',')
x

   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  1  1  0  0
1  1  0  1  1  1
2  0  0  0  1  1
```

Use this to create a new dataframe using `repeat` and array multiplication -

```
v = x.mul(x.columns).values
c = np.arange(1, x.shape[1] + 1)

df = pd.DataFrame(v, columns=c).add_prefix('VLUE') 
df

  VLUE1 VLUE2 VLUE3 VLUE4 VLUE5
0     A     B     C            
1     A           C     D     E
2                       D     E
```

Comment: Merry xmas :-),~~~~~

Comment: You can add it : -) `x.mul(x.columns.values)`

Comment: That is fine:-) , I would like you to add that , for the future visitors man :-)

Comment: @somu Which one?

Comment: Both of the solution worked given by you and Dark :)

Comment: I see issue after code changes using v = x.mul(x.columns).values though df = pd.DataFrame(v, columns=c).add_prefix('VLUE')  produces all the column names correct in the data frame but all values shows NAN.

Comment: @somu Try `v = x.mul(x.columns.values).values`, to prevent misalignment issues...?

Comment: @coldspeed: It worked. Thank you again and Merry Christmas.  I am new to Panda. Could you please explain why the v = x.mul(x.columns.values) was giving NAN. I got the answer by myself after printing v :)

Comment: @somu You're welcome and wish you the same! Could it be that pandas was trying to align the two by index, causing everything to become NaN?

Answer (score 2):

`get_dummies` is the fastest as of I know, here's my try with `value_counts` and `masking` i.e

```
mask = df[0].str.split(',',expand=True).apply(pd.value_counts,1).notna()

pd.DataFrame(np.where(mask,mask.columns,'')).add_prefix('VALU')


  VALU0 VALU1 VALU2 VALU3 VALU4
0     A     B     C            
1     A           C     D     E
2                       D     E
```

Comment: Merry xmas  :-),~~~~~